How to fix error with lower case of parfaitementweb/filament-country-field?
On laravel / filament site I have added plugin from https://github.com/parfaitementweb/filament-country-field
and I want use key of countries just as I use in my db in lowercase.
I try to use map as :
                    Country::make('country')->map(function ($countryItems) {
                    //    dd($countryItems); // if to uncomment I see items collection

                    // But I got error on next :
                        foreach ($countryItems   as $key=>$label) {
                            $countryItems[$key] = \Str::lower($label);
                        }
                        return $countryItems;
                    }),

raised error :
array_keys(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, Closure given

Which way is correct ?
    "laravel/framework": "^10.48.14",
    "filament/filament": "^3.2-stable",
    "parfaitementweb/filament-country-field": "^2.1"

Thanks in advance!

"You've defined $countyItems as a function, but you're trying to iterate over it as if it were an array. Functions are not iterable. To fix this, assign the function's return value to a variable before using it in the foreach loop. For example, $countiesList = $countyItems(); and then iterate over $countiesList."

There is no array_keys() call in the code. Please post the relevant code and the relevant error information. Country::make('country')->tap(dd(...))->map(function...

@Mehrwarz I try :                      `Country::make('country')->map(function ($countryItems) {
$countiesList = $countryItems();
dd($countiesList);
                        foreach ($countryItems   as $key=>$label) {
                            $countryItems[$key] = \Str::lower($label);
                        }
                        return $countryItems;
                    }),`
                      But I got error :  `Object of type Illuminate\Support\Collection is not callable`


@hakre, sorry did not understand your idea, Please detalize

The diagnostic message you show in your question does not show the code that is causing it. It might be okayish to do that in the first place for quick debugging, but if you don't understand it chances are also limited others do if they can't answer it quickly. So you have to leave the terrain of guessing and look deeper to understand. That's the basic "idea" you mention: Too little information in your question for me.
